# Minio, how to authenticate as root so we can run ci unattended docker installs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, client, minio

We are running Minio in an unintended Docker-compose for testing in our team setups. Means 100 deployments per day and we need to get the secret/access keys somehow. But outside manual via the web console, I cannot find how to do this using the ROOT user we sat in Docker-compose at startup.

There seems only ways to do this using secret/access AFTER you create them in the web console.

The command;

```
  mc admin user add local ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

does not work because I cannot authenticate with a root user/pass (well, I don't know how to) and the docs only talk about setting your access to your private/access key, but after deployment, I don't have any yet (which is the point of the question).

Answer (score 1):

I think we can pass the credentials to the docker-compose.yaml file to create the username and password

```
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: admin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
volumes:
  minio_storage: {}
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is; how do I use those credentials to authenticate to mc (the cli client) and then make a secret/access key. The secret/access key answer is in my question, but I cannot find how to authenticate mc to, in this case, admin/admin. It seems all commands work only with secret/access and I do not have those.

Answer (score 0):

With some type of strange naming, the settings you put inside the docker configuration MINIO_ROOT_USER & MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD which I did, actually *are* the same as the ACCESS KEY and SECRET. I did not try more because of the naming that differed, so I assumed they are other things.

I did try this before but it did not work, however it does work. So @siddartha was partially right, but it did not explain that it's exactly the same thing and must work.

Comment: The `MINIO_ROOT_USER`/`MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD` is different `ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. I can get `ACCESS_KEY_ID` by curl but I have no idea how to get `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. It only available by Web UI. If I get it by UI, then I can create `ACCESS_KEY_ID`  and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` by curl.

Comment: I now create the ACCESS_KEY_ID / SECRET_ACCESS_KEY by curl using the MINIO_ROOT_USER/MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD as key/secret. Works well. But so badly documented.

Comment: Can you share how to get ID/SECRET by curl 
 with "MINIO_ROOT_USER/MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD"?